# How to pass login credentials to 3rd party site?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

My company recently purchased another company & I've been tasked with merging the website services of this other company into our own website.

What they want for now, is just a quick fix.  They want for users to be able to log into their account on OUR site.  Then, once logged in, there will be a link for the user to go to this other company's website, bypassing having to re-log in again at this other site.

We already know the username/password of all of their users, so finding the credentials isn't a problem, only passing them in has been a problem.  Our 2 websites are on 2 separate servers, their login page has an ssl cert, & they use php, while ours uses asp.net.

Is there any way to redirect users to their website, without making them log in again?

Thanks

Comment: "We already know the username/password of all of their users" D: oh god

Comment: I'd consider sharing sessions between the sites, but seriously, if you have their unhashed passwords, there's _no_ point having a login system in the first place, it's a disaster waiting to happen

Comment: The best way would likely be to some how communicate a unique session id from one server to the other. the last the you want to do is send their login credentials to the client and then to the other server. Knowing their login information should not be needed for this task.

Comment: We use a "LogonTicket" scheme where we create the ticket based on info in the person's account, then we pass that ticket to the next site and the script authenticates the ticket and if it is valid, logs them in. BTW, both sites have same username/password combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Look into implementing **OpenId Connect** storing passwords in plain text is a big no no.
Take a look at the following

http://openid.net/connect/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q